# An error occurred please run package manager

Tags: apt, package-management, permissions

Can anyone help with the following error

```
An error occurred, please run Package 
Manager from the right-click menu or apt-get 
in a terminal to see what is wrong.
The error message was: 'Unknown Error:
‘<class’apt_pkg.Error’>’ (E:Could not open 
 file var/lib/apt/lists/ 
 dl.cloudsmith.io_public_symfony_stable_deb_ubuntu_dists_jammy_main_binary-
 i386_Packages – open (13: Permission denied)
```

[image]

I tried running the following commands but they didn't work:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` and `sudo apt update`  That will recreate the erased files.

Comment: Thanks tha actually worked

Comment: @nobody looks like you posted your answer in the comment section by mistake ;)

Comment: @Zanna I was sure it has to be a duplicate.